# Использование геттеров/сеттеров в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код, нашел в книге по js. В этом примере нет ошибок. все выводится как надо и выводится 450

```
'use strict';

function CoffeeMachine(power, capacity) {
    var waterAmount = 0;

    this.waterAmount = function(amount) {
        if(!arguments.length)
            return waterAmount;
        if(amount < 0) {
            throw new Error('Значение должно быть положительным!');
        }
        if(amount > capacity) {
            throw new Error('Значение не должно быть больше ' + capacity);
        }
        waterAmount = amount;
    };
}
var coffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine(1000, 500);
coffeeMachine.waterAmount(450);
alert(coffeeMachine.waterAmount());
```

Но в этом примере выводится undefined

```
'use strict';
 function CoffeeMachine(power, capacity) {
        var waterAmount = 0;

        this.waterAmount = function(amount) {
            if(!arguments.length)
                return waterAmount;
            if(amount < 0) {
                throw new Error('Значение должно быть положительным!');
            }
            if(amount > capacity) {
                throw new Error('Значение не дожно быть больше ' + capacity);
            }
            waterAmount = amount;
        };
    }
    var coffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine(1000, 500);
    alert(coffeeMachine.waterAmount(450));
```

Тут я просто в alert записал сразу и все. объясните в чем разница, почему когда не в alert записано то все работает, а наоборот нет.

Comment: `coffeeMachine.waterAmount(450)` и `coffeeMachine.waterAmount()` - разница есть.

Comment: Полный дубликат: [Ошибка при выводе данных JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/943849/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-javascript)

Comment: А какая связь между заголовком вопроса и его текстом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// вызов без параметров - getter - возвращает текущее значение
var a1 = coffeeMachine.waterAmount();
// вызов с параметром - setter - ничего не возвращает 
var a2 = coffeeMachine.waterAmount(123);
console.log(a1, a2);
```

Можете написать

```
    this.waterAmount = function(amount) {
        if(!arguments.length)
            return waterAmount;
        ...
        return waterAmount = amount;
    };
```

Тогда setter будет возвращать новое значение.

Answer (score 0):

смотри ..у тебя происходит следующее-   при первом вызове

```
coffeeMachine.waterAmount(450);
```

у тебя   функция  ничего не отдает так как не выполняются условия  в if  :
 первый  if
  `!arguments.length` -  будет true  если не будет у метода waterAmount  аргументов.. а больше ретурнов и нет. поэтому  метод  ничего не возвращает. но метод  записывает значение

```
waterAmount = amount
```

и при следующем вызове его без параметров  выполнится первый if
  и будет возвращено значение 450. 
отсюда и такое поведение. 
 что бы он сработал в alert - вызови метод с аргументом, а в алерте уже без.

Comment: да..и с сеттерами тут я как-то связи не вижу